# Eclipse IDE --->PDFBox

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

Can anyone tell me why the following parser fails to extract the text?

```
file = new File(filePath);
parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

parser.parse();
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
pdfStripper.setStartPage(a);
pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

System.out.println(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());
Text=pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
```

The console is looping the same output:

```
18:29:34.147 [main] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser - parsed=COSObject{4086, 0}
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. I cannot see a question. What are you asking? Cheers.

Comment: Why the parser is not exacting the text?

Comment: It fails for all PDFs? For a parser question, it is usually good to provide a sample of your input. [perhaps a link in the case of a PDF] But let's see if anyone can help...

Comment: Also be careful with your tags. I added 'pdfbox' to your post. You are unlikely to receive help for a specific API unless it is tagged...

Comment: What does this have to do with eclipse? Please share the PDF, mention what PDFBox version you are using, and check the text extraction FAQ. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction  Btw the easy way to open a file is `PDDocument.load(file);`. The complicated way is outdated and only mentioned in obscure SEO-motivated tutorials.

Comment: Netbeans don't show any error while eclipse is being troublesome.

Comment: You only answered the first of my questions. The three others in the same comment are unanswered (share PDF, mention version of PDFBox, do the things mentioned in the FAQ)